# wrong output from a simple C code block

Tags: c, pointers, static

I expect the output is "Sunday Monday", but the actual output is "Monday Monday",Why this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
static const char *msg[] = {"Sunday", "Monday", 
"Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
char *get_a_day(int idx)
{
    static char buf[20];
    strcpy(buf, msg[idx]);
    return buf;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s %s\n", get_a_day(0), get_a_day(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you use separate `printf` calls?

Comment: sorry I forgot to write a 'return' in last editing... my fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare `buf[]` as `static`, which means there will be exactly one memory location shared by all instances.

`get_a_day()` seems to implicitly return `buf[]`, so both calls to `get_a_day()` return a pointer to the same buffer.

The first call sets `buf[]` to `"Sunday"` and returns a pointer to the memory location of `buf`.  Then the second call sets `buf[]` to `"Monday"`, overwriting `"Sunday"`, and returns a pointer to the memory location of `buf` - the same memory location as the first call did.  Then the pointer to `buf`is passed as the 2nd and 3rd arguments to `printf`.  Since `buf` contains `"Monday"` (having previously overwritten `"Sunday"`), `printf()` prints `Monday Monday`.

Why does `buf` need to be static?  If you remove this keyword and properly allocate your memory, things should work how you hoped.  Also, do you need `buf` at all?  If you just returned `msg[i]`, you'd get the result you expect.

One other thing: you should not be implicitly returning a value like this.  Maintainability substantially drops and the intent of the code isn't clear.  You should explicitly `return` the value you mean to return.

Answer (score 3):

If you want an explanation, the other answers explain it well.

If you just want your program to work, this should fix it:

```
const char *get_a_day(int idx)
{
    return msg[idx];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should enable all warnings (e.g. compile with `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn to use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`).

Notice that your `get_a_day` function is declared to return a `char*` but does not return anything (and your compiler would warn you about that). So you have an [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and everything could happen (and still conforms to C specifications).

Even if you add `return buf;` at the end of your `get_a_day` function, it would return the *same* pointer, since `buf` is `static` (if called twice in a `printf` like you do).

You should perhaps consider returning a heap allocated string, and have the convention that the *caller* should free it. But in your particular case, returning `msg[idx]` is enough.

Comment: Yep should be allocating a new buffer and deleting it at the end. Plus the whole no return thing.

Comment: It doesn't return anything, AND it fills a local buffer `buf`, which then immediately goes out of existence. He apparently meant to return `buf`, but that won't work either (actally, it might work despite being wrong).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: notice that `buf` is declared `static` so the code is not returning a local buffer.

Comment: Ah, so it is. Didn't notice that somehow. Will still have trouble calling it twice inside printf() since there's only one buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Its because you are using strcpy.  strcpy replaces the entire string in the buffer.  As such the second call overwrites the first call (on some platforms the first call will overwrite the second call because they are evaluated in the opposite order).  Not to mention the lack of a return.  Try this code instead:

```
char* get_a_day( int idx, char* buf )
{
    strcpy(buf, msg[idx]);
    return buf;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buf0[20];
    char buf1[20];

    printf("%s %s\n", get_a_day(0, buf0), get_a_day(1, buf1));
    return 0;
}
```